# Group CASE statement on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where orders can have multiple quotes. Now as you can see quotes can be open or cancelled. I am looking to return the orders where every quote on it has been cancelled.

```
Order No     Quote Number    Quote Status
256             12              CANCEL
256             13              OPEN
678             18              CANCEL
678             16              CANCEL
678             19              CANCEL
```

the desired result from this data:

```
Order No     Quote Number    Quote Status
678             16              CANCEL
```

Normal group by clause gives me this result

```
SELECT order No, Min(Quote Number), Min (Quote Status)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Order No

Order No     Quote Number    Quote Status
256             12              CANCEL
678             16              CANCEL
```

But obviosuly this isnt really what i am looking for because it still returns order 256. so it looks cancelled but really it holds an opened quote if that makes sense.

Can anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close.  Just use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT orderNo, MIN(QuoteNumber), MAX(QuoteStatus)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY OrderNo
HAVING MIN(QuoteStatus) = MAX(QuoteStatus) AND MIN(QuoteStatus) = 'Cancelled'
```

Comment: You mean `MIN(Quote Number)` per OP in column 2 of the Select.

Comment: You're a star! Can you explain to me how the MIN(QuoteStatus) = MAX(QuoteStatus) works

Comment: @RyanGadsdon For each grouping OrderNo, if there is a QuoteStatus = 'Open', it will not get picked up because 'Cancelled' = 'Open' condition will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're getting the `Cancel` from `Min()` function, but I think this will work for you as well.

```
SELECT order No, Min(Quote Number), Min (Quote Status)
FROM TABLE
Where [Quote Status] = 'CANCEL'
AND [Order No] NOT IN (Select [Order NO] From TABLE Where [Quote Status] = 'OPEN')
GROUP BY Order No
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
SELECT OrderNo,MIN(QuoteNumber),QuoteStatus 
FROM TABLE
WHERE OrderNo NOT IN (
  SELECT OrderNo FROM TABLE 
  Where QuoteStatus <> 'CANCEL')
GROUP BY OrderNo,QuoteStatus
```

I am assuming that there are no NULL values in the QuoteStatus field. If there are NULLs then instead of `Where QuoteStatus <> 'CANCEL'` write  `Where QuoteStatus <> 'CANCEL' OR QuoteStatus IS NULL`